# Working with HDFS within docker container

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs

I'm reading a book on hadoop, which i'm running locally with docker. I'm using [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/) from sequenceiq and trying to execute this command:

```
./bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /input/docs/quangle.txt hdfs://localhost/user/4lex1v/quangle.txt
```

But it throws an error:

```
copyFromLocal: Call From e9584b413d6a/172.17.0.2 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I don't have such problems running it locally, how can i fix it?

Comment: You should be using e9584b413d6a or 172.17.0.2 instead of localhost.

Comment: You should edit the core-site.xml and put the the GUEST (docker VM) IP (something like 192.168.99.100) and put the port mapped to 8020 instead of 8020 itself. After trying a lot of different things with sequence's image, this solution worked for me.     Example: <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://192.168.99.100:32798</value>